# How can one delay javascript function execution after page refresh?

Tags: javascript

As one new to JavaScript, I have a need to retrieve data from sessionStorage and populate my parent input form after the parent input refreshes to update some child records. I am able to call the function to refresh the page and  the function to get the data from sessionStorage independently, but I have been unable to combine the processes so that a) the page fully reloads, and then b) the data is retrieved from sessionStorage after the page reloads. How can one do this?

My code for the page refresh (with an attempt to combine the functions using a setTimeout method) is as follows:

```
<script> 
function refreshPage() {
location.reload();
setTimeout(GetSessionData, 4000);
}
</script>
```

My function to get data out of sessionStorage is as follows:

```
<script>
var inputcollection = document.getElementsByTagName("input");

function GetSessionData() {
    for (var i = 0; i &lt; inputcollection.length; i++) {
    if(document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name) != null || document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name) != undefined) {
    console.log(i + " " + inputcollection[i].name + "-" + inputcollection [i].value + "-");
    if(document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name).type != "file"){
   document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name).value = sessionStorage.getItem(inputcollection[i].name);
   }}}
</script>
```

Comment: One can not.... The page reloads, anything after is not going to run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are executing your function inside the refreshPage() function it will execute the previous instruction in order to refresh the page location.reload(), so it will refresh the page, the function execution is stopped due to the page reload and the following code pending never executes.

You should put the GetSessionData() function execution after the page refresh/load on the load event for the document body and remove it from the refresh.

```
<html>
  <head>    
  <!--Many things -->
     <script> 
     function refreshPage() {
       location.reload();
     }
     </script>
   </head>
   <body onload="GetSessionData()">
   <!-- Your body code -->
   </body>
</html>
```

If you want to add the delay with the setTimeOut function you should put into another function or inside the GetSessionData

```
function GetSessionData() {
     setTimeOut(function(){
         for (var i = 0; i < inputcollection.length; i++) {
           if(document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name) != null || 
           document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name) != undefined) {
               console.log(i + " " + inputcollection[i].name + "-" + 
               inputcollection [i].value + "-");
               if(document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name).type != "file"){
                    document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name).value = sessionStorage.getItem(inputcollection[i].name);
                }
           }
         }
       },4000);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - that was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
<script> 

    //Declare your function
    function GetSessionData() {
        for (var i = 0; i &lt; inputcollection.length; i++) {
            if(document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name) != null || document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name) != undefined) {
                console.log(i + " " + inputcollection[i].name + "-" + inputcollection [i].value + "-");
                if(document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name).type != "file"){
                    document.getElementById(inputcollection[i].name).value = sessionStorage.getItem(inputcollection[i].name);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //When the page is loaded (or reloaded in your case), set theTimeout which will call the GetSessionData, 
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        setTimeout(GetSessionData, 4000);
    });

    //Declaring your refresh function
    function refreshPage() {
        location.reload();
    }
</script>
```